# Debian and system clock change?

Tags: linux, debian, time

If I change my system time on Debian which files would be modified?

Would it be /etc/default/rcS?

Also, is default time on Debian Dec 31 1969?

Comment: [Everything you need is here (Debian Wiki/DateTime).](http://wiki.debian.org/DateTime) [More info here (the freshly translated debian-handbook).](http://static.debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.config-misc.html#section.synchronisation-horaire)

Answer (score 4):

Current time information is not stored in a file, rather it's synced from your hardware clock with `/sbin/hwclock` during boot. Seeing this date, usually means, your system clock has been reset, this is often caused by a faulty battery on your system board (a CMOS battery),

[image]

The date [Dec 31 1969](http://www.mentalfloss.com/blogs/archives/72227) is the epoch date (representing this number in bits this would be all zeros), when your system resets the system clock, it is reset to the epoch date (all zeros).

**How to fix the issue**

1. Set your current time with `date` (directions are in `man date`)
2. Sync your hwclock to the system time, `hwclock --systohc`

And you're back in business. For continual syncing of the clock with an external source you should look at `ntp`.

If you would like to test your CMOS battery, the simplest way to do so is to shutdown your system, remove the power cord, wait for about 5 minutes (to remove stand-by power, and let the capacitors drain), then start everything back up. If your clock has reset again, get a new battery. You can usually find the correct battery at a drugstore. If this is a server, you should contact your vendor for a replacement (ASAP).

I'm not aware of any mechanism within Linux that would allow you to monitor the state of your CMOS battery.

Comment: Don't most BIOSes reset to 1/1/1980 or 1/1/2000 or something?

Comment: Seconded. Last time I made use of CMOS reset, the default was 2002/1/1. This date is the default for about every post-2002 BIOS since there aren't that many date bits in the CMOS.

Comment: @moshbear if Unix time is a 32 bit number how many bits are in the CMOS? And how does it "upscale" from a lower value?

Comment: It probably returns the CMOS value incremented by some constant in the BIOS.

Comment: It's actually a 72 bit number (if I am reading this right). 9 registers of 1 byte each (I don't think they are signed values either): http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#Getting_Current_Date_and_Time_from_RTC So it's not that it runs out of space ... I think it gets reset to whatever the manufacturer wants.

Comment: You should also note that `ntp` will refuse to change the time if the difference between the server's time and the local host's time is too great (it's a security feature). I'm not sure how/if you can change this, but `ntpdate` doesn't care and it's a good tool to have in this case (bring down your `ntpd` temporarily before using it).